# Change the format of 'Authored on' date in views filter

Tags: 8, datetime

In Drupal 8, I want to remove the timestamp on 'Authored on' date in views filter. Any Idea how to do this?

[image]

Comment: What module are you using for this filter widget? Date popup and Better exposed filters with jQuery UI Datepicker already behave that way, without the time option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @prkos that worked. I was using patch from this link -> https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2648950 which added time field too.
But now I removed the patch and added the Date popup module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @prkos said enable [better_exposed_filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) and in `Exposed form style` change it as `Better Exposed Filters`. Open setting and under `Authored On` select `jQuery UI Datepicker`. It will enable to give only date format.

**BEF Settings:**

[image]